# Terminal in WebStorm shows text in weird colors

Tags: terminal, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a problem i terminal in WebStorm. Running any command make all text have weird blue background for no reason. Any came across same problem ? Thanks for help :)

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've set up PowerShell as a cmd in File | Settings | Tools | Terminal - this is not supported currently

Comment: Using cmd gives me same result. I've tested it with couple commands and it seems that only Ionic CLI has this kind of problems. Maybe that's the case ?